# How to find and replace multiple values from mapping (key value pairs) in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, replace, find, spreadsheet

I have a sheet with data for rankings for hundreds of people. My data is anonymous, and instead of using the names of the people, I have UID numbers.

I'm trying to find and replace the UID numbers with a mapping that shows, in key-value pairs, which UID corresponds to which person.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Google Sheet sample problem with only 10 people:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dsLpFBNTmhC3ISoYrJFPhEleBo_W5mrK9MSz-V7ZasE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Mapping!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,TRUE
```

ON 1st Sheet Column C